# Why can't you filter a custom post type by a category name?

Tags: wordpress

The category slug exists and is assigned to many posts.
Removing the category_name from the args then shows all the custom posts.
What is the correct way for filtering the posts by category name?

```
   <?php

   $args = array(
       'post_type'       => 'Resource',
       'category_name' => 'activity-sheets'
   );


   $loop = new WP_Query($args);

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
```

Comment: activity-sheets is taxonomy name or category?

Comment: activity-sheets is a category

Comment: What is your custom taxonomy name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tax_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) for custom post-type custom taxonomy. check my below code.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'Resource',
       'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy-name',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'activity-sheets',
            ),
        ),
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        // your code
    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```